# whatsapp how to extract hash from keystore.xml

Tags: python, whatsapp

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<map>

<string name="server_static_public">qJWvSttNopqgQ2CgXYTc4jmSUKWd1Rv2QTMbQyYpKwY</string>

<string name="client_static_keypair_enc">[0,"s62vHltkeT3lP9cJD4fYiXlqMpnfCy\/lpQ5DXkPDgDvE0FzdBK\/52kQIJ\/cHAE+cx\/YynQFb\/V2OAKTWaKbhbUTVF7AtYc7ObiYi1NDicOM","Iy5pL5mCD5my9Ce4"]</string>

<long name="client_static_keypair_enc_success" value="6"/>

<boolean name="can_user_android_key_store" value="true"/>

<string name="client_static_keypair_pwd_enc">[2,"Zeu0mZ\/1KHNRPlSD3NCAyqXk+0Jy9BQzqnOOSGpDaZk1iq\/2g+ZQRpZpVBTdgY1GAIl+LAmZuzGQrc3Wg8jGKw","c16SyxGwPgcSscZu7Aq0hg","0YXK+g","3x7RocV+jSfcYyNwg8gxwQ"]</string>

</map>
```

How to convert the data in client_static_keypair_pwd_enc into correct data?
The correct data is:
key1:P2u4BDU15Uu2pGpS5zC6/IPpjTDE5KnQxeDNpunroig=
key2:0JsAvVC6lG6n05fQOYHXO6Q2ONebLJ4UMPg88rO4yEE=

Brother, can you help me? thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please refrain from posting credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job modules like BeautifulSoup4 could help you with. It can be installed by running `pip install beautifulsoup4` in your terminal or cmd and the documentation can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

you can see this:
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/discussions/3056

```
import json
import base64
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

TOKEN_RAW = [
    0x41, 0x04, 0x1d, 0x40, 0x11, 0x18, 0x56, 0x91, 0x02, 0x90,
    0x88, 0x9f, 0x9e, 0x54, 0x28, 0x33, 0x7b, 0x3b, 0x45, 0x53
]
TOKEN = bytes(map(lambda x: x ^ 0x12, TOKEN_RAW))


def base64_decode(text):
    return base64.b64decode(text + '==')


def decrypt(password, iv, salt, ciphertext):
    password_ = TOKEN + password
    password_ = ''.join(map(chr, password_)).encode()  # b'\x83' => b'\xc2\x83'
    key = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1', password_, salt, 16, 16)
    return AES.new(key, AES.MODE_OFB, iv).decrypt(ciphertext)


def decrypt_keypair(keypair_pwd_enc):
    json_text = keypair_pwd_enc.replace('&quot;', '"').replace('\/', '/')
    json_data = json.loads(json_text)
    version, ciphertext, iv, salt, password = json_data

    assert version == 2
    ciphertext = base64_decode(ciphertext)
    iv = base64_decode(iv)
    salt = base64_decode(salt)
    password = password.encode()

    result = decrypt(password, iv, salt, ciphertext)
    return base64.b64encode(result).decode()


def test():
    client_static_keypair_pwd_enc = '[2,&quot;Leol3AoKXTUQxihhB0hUNgWueQo0E59PuYTxs9WJPktis56ZcRb2ZPXI9rOzKmXCaNO+wNIcGWsitAo\/Ijum0w&quot;,&quot;2P2WJHXo7uFHGh3k7uUaDQ&quot;,&quot;HFYgAg&quot;,&quot;m3Uq1DOgWw6FhKSMgUgJnQ&quot;]'
    result = decrypt_keypair(client_static_keypair_pwd_enc)
    print('client_static_keypair:\n' + result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```